# Generic way to filter django query set by multiple fields (e.g. date)?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm trying to create a generic date class based view for the blog I'm creating, but it does not seem to work. This is what I've got (regex inspired by [this gist](https://gist.github.com/c4urself/1028897)):

```
"""Creativeflow URL Configuration the blog app."""
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import BlogListView, BlogDetailView
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'posts/(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<months>\d{2}|\w{3})/(?P<day>\d{2})/(?P<slug>\w+)',
        BlogDetailView.as_view(), name="blog-detail"),
    url(r'posts(?:/(?P<year>\d{4}))(?:/(?P<months>\d{2}|\w{3}))?(?:/(?P<day>\d{2}))?',
        BlogListView.as_view(paginate_by=25), name="blog-list"),
]
```

And my views:

```
class BlogListView(ListView):
    """CBV for list of blog posts."""

    model = Post
    context_object_name = "blog_objects"

    def get_query_set(self):
        """Get the posts in the specified date range.

        Year defaults to todays year
        Month defaults to last month of the year
        Day defaults to last day of the month
        """
        now = datetime.now()
        year = self.kwargs.get('year', now.year)
        month = self.kwargs.get('month', 12)
        day = self.kwargs.get('day', calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1])
        date = datetime.date(year=year,
                             month=month,
                             day=day)
        print(date)
        print('hello')
        return Post.objects.filter(published__lt=date)
```

Going to `http://blog.creativeflow.org.uk/posts/2016/07/09` doesn't provide any data up to the template, `post_list.html`:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <main>
        {% for  blog in blog_objects %}
            <div>
                <h3>{{ blog.title }}</h3>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </main>
{% endblock content %}
```

(I can provide the base as well if people want)

My intention is that accessing `posts/2016` gets all of 2016s posts (because it defaults to the end of 2016, i.e. `2016/12/31`), `posts/2016/02` gets all of the posts from February 2016 (defaults to the end of Feb 2016, i.e. `2016/02/29`) etc. But running  `resolve('/posts/2016/07/09')` produces an error because I'm on a subdomain, and using django-subdomain's [`from subdomains.utils import reverse`](https://django-subdomains.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#resolving-named-urls-by-subdomain) works...

```
>>> reverse('blog-list', subdomain="blog", kwargs={"year":"2016", "months":"02", "day":"13"})
'http://blog.creativeflow.org.uk/posts/2016/02/13'
```

but my attempt in the browser don't return anything. I'm also not getting anything printed in the terminal when I refresh the page, despite my two print statements.

I feel like there is something drastic that I'm missing that's obvious, but I'm struggling to connect the dots.

How can I make this route work?

Comment: What's the difference between your homebrew solution and [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/generic-date-based/)?

Comment: You are using the keyword `months` in your url pattern but `month` when you try to reverse.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist that method requires multiple views for each subset, when it's just a single view I want with different levels of filtering.

Comment: @Alasdair thanks that now works, but I'm still not getting any objects on my page

Comment: does the `print(date)` actually print the date as expected?

Comment: Note that currently you are filtering using `lt`, so if you specify `<url>/2016` it will find all posts published **strictly before** year 2016. Maybe you wanted to use the `gt`/`ge` filter?

Comment: @ohrstrom it doesn't seem to print *anything*. NB. the django dev server prints the current date by default.

Comment: @Bakuriu it should default to posts in `2016/12/31` if only the year is specified, from the docstring: `Year defaults to todays year, Month defaults to last month of the year, Day defaults to last day of the month` Let me know if it's not doingthat

Comment: @Pureferret sorry - i don't understand hat you mean with "the django dev server prints the current date by default". but for sure you have to make sure first that the `date` object you feed into the query is correct.

Comment: @ohrstrom When you just run the Django Dev server it prints out various stuff...`System check identified no issues (0 silenced). July 11, 2016 - 15:35:52 Django version 1.9.6, using settings 'creativeflow.settings.development'` etc. That's not the date I'm trying to print out though.

Comment: @Pureferret that's not of importance here... ok - at least your system's time seems to be correct :)

Comment: @ohrstrom just making sure I'm not getting anything mixed up. :)

Comment: DB must have been wiped at some point. Put some blogs in and it works. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

This works, my two main issues were

1. Not having blogs in the DB
2. As [Alasdair said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38309270/generic-way-to-filter-django-query-set-by-multiple-fields-e-g-date#comment64035617_38309270):

   > You are using the keyword months in your url pattern but month when you try to reverse.

I believe that's all it took to resolve this.